# Image Scaled Big

Tags: android, wallpaper

I tried to set wallpaper in my device using this function.

```
void setWallpaper() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(metrics);

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    String imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + getImageName();
    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagepath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height,
            true);
    bitmap.recycle();
    if (imagepath != null) {
        System.out.println("Hi I am trying to set wallpaper");
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(context);
        Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting a bigger scaled images. i.e some portion of the image is out of the screen. How can I change this code to make it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hope below will help you:

```
public static Bitmap getZoomBitmap(int mMaxWidth, int mMaxHeight,
        InputStream in) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // If we have to resize this image, first get the natural bounds.
    decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, decodeOptions);
    int actualWidth = decodeOptions.outWidth;
    int actualHeight = decodeOptions.outHeight;

    // Then compute the dimensions we would ideally like to decode to.
    int desiredWidth = getResizedDimension(mMaxWidth, mMaxHeight,
            actualWidth, actualHeight);

    int desiredHeight = getResizedDimension(mMaxHeight, mMaxWidth,
            actualHeight, actualWidth);

    // Decode to the nearest power of two scaling factor.
    decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    // TODO(ficus): Do we need this or is it okay since API 8 doesn't
    // support it?
    // decodeOptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed =
    // PREFER_QUALITY_OVER_SPEED;
    int sampleSize = findBestSampleSize(actualWidth, actualHeight,
            desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
    decodeOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
    Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, decodeOptions);
    // If necessary, scale down to the maximal acceptable size.
    if (tempBitmap != null
            && (tempBitmap.getWidth() > desiredWidth || tempBitmap
                    .getHeight() > desiredHeight)) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, desiredWidth,
                desiredHeight, true);
        tempBitmap.recycle();
    } else {
        bitmap = tempBitmap;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
    /**
 * Scales one side of a rectangle to fit aspect ratio.
 * 
 * @param maxPrimary
 *            Maximum size of the primary dimension (i.e. width for max
 *            width), or zero to maintain aspect ratio with secondary
 *            dimension
 * @param maxSecondary
 *            Maximum size of the secondary dimension, or zero to maintain
 *            aspect ratio with primary dimension
 * @param actualPrimary
 *            Actual size of the primary dimension
 * @param actualSecondary
 *            Actual size of the secondary dimension
 */
public static int getResizedDimension(int maxPrimary, int maxSecondary,
        int actualPrimary, int actualSecondary) {
    // If no dominant value at all, just return the actual.
    if (maxPrimary == 0 && maxSecondary == 0) {
        return actualPrimary;
    }

    // If primary is unspecified, scale primary to match secondary's scaling
    // ratio.
    if (maxPrimary == 0) {
        double ratio = (double) maxSecondary / (double) actualSecondary;
        return (int) (actualPrimary * ratio);
    }

    if (maxSecondary == 0) {
        return maxPrimary;
    }

    double ratio = (double) actualSecondary / (double) actualPrimary;
    int resized = maxPrimary;
    if (resized * ratio > maxSecondary) {
        resized = (int) (maxSecondary / ratio);
    }
    return resized;
}

/**
 * Returns the largest power-of-two divisor for use in downscaling a bitmap
 * that will not result in the scaling past the desired dimensions.
 * 
 * @param actualWidth
 *            Actual width of the bitmap
 * @param actualHeight
 *            Actual height of the bitmap
 * @param desiredWidth
 *            Desired width of the bitmap
 * @param desiredHeight
 *            Desired height of the bitmap
 */
public static int findBestSampleSize(int actualWidth, int actualHeight,
        int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight) {
    double wr = (double) actualWidth / desiredWidth;
    double hr = (double) actualHeight / desiredHeight;
    double ratio = Math.min(wr, hr);
    float n = 1.0f;
    while ((n * 2) <= ratio) {
        n *= 2;
    }

    return (int) n;
}
```